# Tutorial to sett-up AWS Cognito, IAM, AWS Gateway, Lambda function with authenticated caller

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm using AWS Cognito, Sync, IAM, API Gateway and Lambda.

I have a Lambda function my iOS app calls using API Gateway (using the code this system generates), that only works when an iOS user is authenticated. When authenticated, the Lambda returns a value correctly.

When I change the function to return the `context.identity` or `context.identity.cognito_identity_id` my iOS app gets back `nil`

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return context.identity
```

I realise that much can go wrong in configuring AWS Cognito, Sync, IAM, API Gateway and Lambda to work together - the Mobile Hub feels very undeveloped.

So I ask for a tutorial rather than than trying to post all my settings for four AWS systems. The client used need not be iOS/Swift.

Comment: I found the "Invoke with caller credentials" checkbox under Method Execution "Integration Request" but building a method with this turn on, rebuilding the iOS files didn't change: context.identity in my lambda function is still nil while fields like context.function_name hold a valid value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user's credentials (of Cognito) are in event not context.
Look there and GET, POST et al all have the user's credentials.